# WP7 Handling a Database with MVVMLight

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am working with MVVMLight in Windows Phone 7 for the first time. I THINK I have finally wrapped my brain around some of it. However, one area I am struggling with is where to create an instance of my database so that I only have one connection to it. I have two models in my project, each of which I want to have their own DataService. Is there someway to pass in a db connection to the constructor of the DataService? Or would I do something like create a singleton of a DB connection object when the app starts? Or am I completely on the wrong track and there is a much better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that the DI container in MVVM Light treats all of its registrations as singletons by default, so if multiple view models have your DataService injected into them they'll be using the same instance of the object without you having to do anything.

How you handle creating the DB connection really depends on the DB you're using (SQL-CE, SQLLite, etc).